# guest failed to start: Failure in libvirt_lxc startup: Failed to bind mount directory /.oldroot/bootflash/a1 to /bootflash/a1: No such file o

Tags: libvirt

I am using Linux Linux with libvirt 5.5.0
I have two volumes to be mounted in guest one from usb(in ext4) and one from bootflash(in ext2)

Snippets from my XML looks like this

```
<emulator>/usr/sbin/libvirt_lxc</emulator>
<filesystem type="mount">
    <source dir="/vol/usb1/c1/rootfs_mnt"/>
    <target dir="/"/>
</filesystem>
<filesystem type="mount">
    <source dir="/bootflash/a1"/>
    <target dir="/bootflash/a1"/>
</filesystem>
```

virsh -c lxc:/// start try
error: Failed to start domain try
error: internal error: guest failed to start: Failure in libvirt_lxc startup: Failed to bind mount directory /.oldroot/bootflash/a1 to /bootflash/a1: No such file o

Could someone pls help me here?